# Virtualization software that supports mounting host zfs zpool

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualization, mount, zfs

what virtualization software should be used for a guest operating system (preferably BSD) that supports mounting host(Linux) zpools in the guest OS?

I am aware of the vmware ability to mount hard disks in the guest OS, but can that ability be used for zpools to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare Workstation will certainly allow this. Add a hard drive and mark that you want to "Use a physical disk (for advanced users)". You can choose the entire disk or use individual partitions.

Of course, nothing will allow both the host and the guest to mount the file system at the same time. That's a restriction of the file system, though, rather than a problem with your virtualisation software.